# Is it possible to dispute being reported as a scammer?

Tags: steam

I am new to steam trading, and today I found that I have been reported as a scammer.

I do not know why, I didn't invite anyone to trade with me in the same time. All the trades I have done were in the forum posts - I send a trade offer and the other person accepts or declines.

So can this report be disputed or removed?

Comment: *Where* have you been reported as a scammer? If you don't know where, a link to your Steam profile *might* help.

Comment: i dont know but i think in the cs go trade forum

Comment: Can you look up your account on [SteamRep.com](http://steamrep.com/) and tell me what it says your reputation is?

Comment: Without knowing where you've been reported as a scammer, it's hard to say how you would dispute it... SteamRep is the biggest place for this and since you're not marked as a scammer there, you should be fine for the most part.